# Are the phrases "comes down to" and "boils down to" interchangeble?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases, idiomatic-language, phrase-choice

I do get the meaning of the phrases separately, but I would like to know if they can be used interchangeably at least in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equivalent. They express that you are stating the crux of some issue.